# Generating pander tables in a loop in RMarkdown in Rstudio

Tags: r, for-loop, rstudio, knitr, pander

I've a set of tables that I'm generating with use of the code similar to the snippet below:

````
```{r tables, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE}
require(reshape2); require(pander)
data("mtcars")
data("AirPassengers")

dta_lst <- list(mtcars, AirPassengers)
for (i in 1:length(dta_lst)) {
    pander(melt(head(dta_lst[[i]], n = 2), varnames = c("Something"), 
            value.name = "Something else"), 
           caption = paste("Some table for: ", class(dta_lst[[i]])))
}
```
````

When I run the code it produces the desired output (naturally, the provided example makes little sense, in my proper data I melt the data in sensible manner):

```
---------------------------
 variable   Something else 
---------- ----------------
   mpg            21       

   mpg            21       

   cyl            6        

   cyl            6        

   disp          160       

   disp          160       

    hp           110       

    hp           110       

   drat          3.9       

   drat          3.9       

    wt           2.62      

    wt          2.875      

   qsec         16.46      

   qsec         17.02      

    vs            0        

    vs            0        

    am            1        

    am            1        

   gear           4        

   gear           4        

   carb           4        

   carb           4        
---------------------------

Table: Some table for:  data.frame


----------------
 Something else 
----------------
      112       

      118       
----------------

Table: Some table for:  ts
```

When I attempt to knit the code in Rstudio the pander tables do not appear:

[image: absent tables]

Naturally, without the loop the `pander` command works just fine and generates the tables that are neatly knitted into a HTML document.

Comment: In a nutshell, disable the `knitr.auto.asis` setting in `panderOptions` and use the `results='asis'` chunk option in `knitr`. I will also provide a more detailed answer soon, until then, see this related thread: https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/142#issuecomment-66619769

Comment: @daroczig, thanks very much for showing the interest. I used to suggest combination and it worked as advertised. On a more generic matter, will `panderOptions('knitr.auto.asis', FALSE)` have an impact on how other `pander` tables area treated in the Rmd file? In addition to the loop described above I'm using pander here and there to derive some more standard tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the for loop there is not 'output screen' unless you use the `print(x)` function.

`for (i in 1:4) { i }`  does not display anything

`for (i in 1:4) {print(i)}` displays the Numbers 1 2 3 and 4

Solution: In the FOR loop construct the table (using  knitt) and assign it into a variable. Then print out this variable using `print()` function. Remember. You Must add blank lines after and before the var table: use paste function inside `print()`

Comment: Specifically for pandoc, you need to use `cat` instead of `print`.