# Rmarkdown 2 column layout in a loop

Tags: r, r-markdown

i'm trying to make a loop with 2 column in rmarkdown html :

- two column in each chapter
- chapters made inside`R ,results='asis'` loop

i tried to combine [multi column](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html) and [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199368/how-to-use-a-for-loop-in-rmarkdown) and it's not working
i'm tryng some frankenstein code with raw html in asis chunk and it's not working

> ````
> ---
> title: "test"
> output: html_document
> ---
>
>
> ```{r , echo=FALSE , results='asis'}
>
> for (i in 1:2){
>     cat(' \n# titre ', i , " \n ") 
> cat("htmltools::HTML('<div style=\"display: flex;\">')" , " \n ")  
> cat("blabla col 1" , ' \n')
> cat("htmltools::HTML('</div>')" , " \n ")
> cat("htmltools::HTML('<div>')" , " \n ")
> cat("blabla col 2" , ' \n')
> cat("htmltools::HTML('</div>')" , " \n ")
> cat("htmltools::HTML('</div>')" , " \n ")
> }
>   
> ```
> ````

Comment: I'm not familiar with `htmltools::HTML` but I suspect you need to either call `cat` with HTML code or do something with `htmltools::HTML` outside of `cat` or at least outside of `cat`'s quotes?

Comment: i tried both and they are not working `cat('<div>')` and `htmltools::HTML('<div>')`